# Readline function using a string in place of an integer

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to write a python script that will initialize an automated test based on a number of parameters that are passed during execution. One of the parameters is used as device selection control in a text file that is being used in a readline() call in place of an integer.

How do I make the following work w/o causing an error during use:

```
with open('file.txt') as x:
     head1 = x.readline('APS5000[]')
     linenumber = 3
     if not APU == head1:
            for line in x.readline(linenumber):
                print line
                linenumber += 1
                if x.readline(linenumber) is ('====================================================')
                      linenumber = 14
                break
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what behaviour did you actually expect, but there are a number of errors in the code:

- The argument to `readlines()` needs to be a number of bytes as a hint for the buffer size. This is most likely not what you expected here.
- String as an argument to `readline()` is completely incorrect. Were you trying to read the lines until that value?
- You can't compare strings using `is`. Use `==` instead.

Try to rewrite the code as a single loop of `for line in x:` - this will give you one line of the file at a time. Keep some state variables if needed to make sure which line are you on and what have you seen so far.

Alternatively you can read the whole file into an array with `contents = x.readlines()` and process it from there.

Comment: the is in the if statement is to check if the line being read equals the string that is all, if it is correct then the next line of code is correct otherwise the loop breaks the operation